# Is it possible to restore an iPhone to a newer version of iOS that is not the latest?

Tags: ios, software-update

I would like to install iOS 11 on my iPhone 6 that has iOS 10, but the only possible update that I can see is directly to iOS 12.4.6. Can I update to a newer version that is not the latest?

Answer (score 1):

The way I found is:

1. Download the desired image from https://ipsw.me/
2. Put the iPhone in recovery mode.
3. Open iTunes and Option + click (or Shift + click on Windows) on Update.
4. Locate the image and follow the instructions.